# How can I use switch in enum?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Here is an enum:

```
public enum Size
{
    Normal = 1,
    Small =2
}
```

Now the enum is working in Xamarin and I want it to return a different value on different platforms.

For example the `Normal`:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
  case Device.iOS:
    return 1;
  case Device.Android:
    return 2;
  case Device.UWP:
  default:
    return 3;
}
```

I want to use the enum directly but not declare one more variable or void, just like the `NamedSize` property(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts) in Xamarin.

I mean, is there any way something just like:

```
public enum Size
{
    Normal =>{
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
          case Device.iOS:
            return 1;
          case Device.Android:
            return 2;
          case Device.UWP:
          default:
            return 3;
        }
    },
    Small=2
}
```

How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: `enum` support only constants at declaration, your last snippet won't work on such way

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But how can NamedSize property of Xamarin achieve it? Is it in a different way?

Comment: You can search at their [github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/search?p=1&q=NamedSize&unscoped_q=NamedSize) to see, how it's implemented

Comment: Through the magic of open source software you can look for yourself to see how they do it. They do not simply use an enum, the [FontSizeConverter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FontSizeConverter.cs) class calls on the [Device class](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Device.cs) to derive the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really great question, and you are right that they have found a way to do it using Xamarin. I tried this little experiment that should work:

**Failed Trial 1** - `Device.OnPlatform(0,2,1)`-The essentially let you use a different value depending on the platform (iOS, Android, Windows). So I put this into my VS:

```
public enum Size
{
    Normal =  Device.OnPlatform(0,2,1),
    Small = true ? 1 : 0
}
```

But I got an error saying `The expression being assigned to 'Size.Normal' must be constant`. The reason is because an enum is just a class where each of the members are of type `const`, so they can only contain a constant value.

**Failed Trial 2** - So I tried instead using simple C# to see if providing different values is possible at all

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static int Size(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
public enum Size
{
    Normal =  Utils.Size(2),
    Small = true ? 1 : 0
}
```

And, as you'd expect, I got the same error saying `The expression being assigned to 'Size.Normal' must be constant`.

**But how is Xamarin doing it?**

So I went to the declaration of NamedSize's properties in Xamarin Forms, and as you can see, it is in fact a constant. [image: Screenshot showing NamedSize property in Assembly Browser]
When they assign a NamedSize value to a variable, they are likely doing the check `Enum.GetNames(typeof(NamedSize))` at that instance in the getter of the FontSize property, and if that's not null, they assign the font size variable values.

**So How can you achieve something similar?**

You can follow the route that `Device` takes and create a static class instead of using an enum, and then you'll be able to use it in the same way, as shown:

```
public class Size
{
    public static int Normal => Device.OnPlatform(0, 2, 1);
    public const int Small = 3; // Const if the value won't change
}
...
// Inside your View code
label.FontSize = Size.Normal;
```

PS: Device.OnPlatform is deprecated, so if you want to avoid it, you can do this:

```
public static int Normal
{
    get
    {
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                return 1;
            case Device.Android:
                return 2;
            case Device.UWP:
            default:
                return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enums are really just `int`s. Do a cast:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
  case Device.iOS:
    return (Size)1;
  case Device.Android:
    return (Size)2;
... etc
```

But if you are hard-coding the numbers anyway, why not...?

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
  case Device.iOS:
    return Size.Normal;
  case Device.Android:
    return Size.Small;
... etc
```

> Update

I'm not sure I'm following you but is this what you want? This way you can use `Size` directly.

```
public enum Size
{
    Normal = Device.iOS, Small = Device.Android
}
```

Comment: In your way, I have to declare a new variable or void. I don't want to do it like this but use the enum directly. NamedSize property in Xamarin is just like this, it will return a different value in the enum while different platform.

Comment: As you see in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts:NamedSize enum property will return a different integer value in different platform. That's what I need.

Comment: That link goes nowhere. Can you edit your question to show examples of code and what you expect the result to be on each platform?

Comment: Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't know how Xamarin achieved it. But it exists indeed.